# How to push square bracket in JSON without having square Bracket Using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

**Here is the json we want to push the square bracket using jquery..**

```
{"ProductionAnticipationId":{"title":"","type":"hidden","required":true,"options":"","defaultValue":""},"ProductionType": {"title": "Production Type","type": "Combobox","required": true,"options": "/BgtProduction/GetProductionType","unique": true},"Grade": {"title": "Grade","type": "Combobox","required": true,"options": "/BgtProduction/GetGrades","unique": true},"Quantity": {"title": "Quantity ","type": "","required": true,"align":"right","defaultValue": "0"} },{"Quantity":"total"}
```

Here is the code we used to push square bracket to above  JSON..

```
    var ar = [];
    if (!$.isArray(l_schemaString))

        ar = ar.push($.parseJSON(l_schemaString));
    else


        ar = $.parseJSON(l_schemaString);
```

Once we apply this code in View , shows an error in console as,
***Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,***

Please give a solution to resolve this issue

Comment: FYI, in javascript `square bracket == array`

Comment: sorry, i can't catch up..:(

Comment: yes, square bracket defines an array.. but if the defined schema is not an array we need to push square bracket into it.. after pushing the square bracket using above code it shows an exception in console

Comment: You can only `push()` to an array, no other types have a push method

Comment: we need to push the parseJSON(l_schemaString)

Comment: Well, the unexpected token error seems to indicate that you're trying to parse a string that isn't really a string, or that the JSON is not valid. Are you sure you're not trying to parse a javascript object here, as that would fail miserably.

Comment: how to parse a javascript object?

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your JSON into a formatter here: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

And the result was: **Error: Multiple JSON root elements**

```
{
   "ProductionAnticipationId":{
      "title":"",
      "type":"hidden",
      "required":true,
      "options":"",
      "defaultValue":""
   },
   "ProductionType":{
      "title":"Production Type",
      "type":"Combobox",
      "required":true,
      "options":"/BgtProduction/GetProductionType",
      "unique":true
   },
   "Grade":{
      "title":"Grade",
      "type":"Combobox",
      "required":true,
      "options":"/BgtProduction/GetGrades",
      "unique":true
   },
   "Quantity":{
      "title":"Quantity ",
      "type":"",
      "required":true,
      "align":"right",
      "defaultValue":"0"
   }
},                                 <-- the problem is here
{
   "Quantity":"total"
}
```

It looks like the problem is that the JSON has multiple objects in it, not just one. So this should be written as `[ ... objects here ... ]` when it is written out by the server so that they get wrapped in an array.

In the other code examples, there is a problem here:

```
ar = ar.push($.parseJSON(l_schemaString));
```

The [push method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array, so `ar` will end up being set to `1` instead of being an array, which will cause problems later.

Comment: Yes the Problem is Above Quantity, but we need to take the Total of quantity. it will be work fine after pushing square bracket into the schema.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "pushing square bracket into the schema". You'll need to write out valid JSON before the JavaScript will be able to work with it.

Comment: var ar = [];
        if (!$.isArray(l_schemaString))

            ar = ar.push($.parseJSON(l_schemaString));
        else


            ar = $.parseJSON(l_schemaString);  l_schemaString is the schema.                                the schema should be defined in array format.. right? we need to make the above schema as array format by using this code but if we use this code shows an error.. is there any error in the code??

Comment: Yes, there's an error in that code too which I describe at the end of my answer. But it looks like that code isn't even running, because the JSON is invalid so it doesn't get that far.